# What is the life story of Srimati ubhaya bhArati?

Tags: vedas, adi-shankaracharya, dharma-shastras

In the well known debate of sankara and manDaNa miSra his wife ubhaya bhaarati also took part.

What was her background and important life events?

I am also specifically looking for verses which talks of her education and wisdom and the fact that she was well versed in shaastras including VEDAS and VEDANGAS